# Drop NaN but keep None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Both None and NaN values indicate the same meaning but in my data frame, I would like to keep rows with None Values and drop with NaN values.

Let us say I have the following data frame df.

df

```
Col_1   Col_2  Col3
None     None   None
1         2      3 
NaN       NaN    NaN
```

When I drop Values with `NaN` I would like to get something like this.

`df.dropna()`

```
Col_1  Col_2   Col_3
None    None    None 
1       2        3
```

But it is droping both None and NaN values.

But to keep None values I tried to fill with other value something like

`df['Col_1].replace({None: 'Empty'}, inplace=True)`

it is filling including NaN values.

My question is, is there any way to drop values with `NaN` and keeping Values `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set values to strings and compare not equal to `NaN` or `nan`s values:

```
df = df[~df.astype(str).isin(['NaN', 'nan']).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
  Col_1 Col_2  Col3
0  None  None  None
1     1     2     3
```

Comment: Is this to change to ```String```? If so doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Kapital - It seems some data related problem.

Comment: @Kapital - Is possible create dictionary of data for testing? Like `print (df.to_dict('l'))`

Comment: I think you need to chain more than one condition here

Comment: I think its not what op wants, they just want to drop NaN, keep the rest

Comment: Any idea why mine could cause problems @jez ?

Comment: @yatu - Not idea, really.

Answer (score 0):

What makes this a little tricky is that pandas treats `None` like `NaN` for the most part, making [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) or [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) the wrong approach here since rows containing `None` will be set to `True` too. What you can do is work with the underlying numpy arrays, which enables us to compare with a `None`:

```
df[((df.to_numpy() == None) | df.notna()).any(1)]

  Col_1 Col_2  Col3
0  None  None  None
1     1     2     3
```

Comment: Are your None's strings or actual None @Kapital ?

Comment: Yes. That is the actual None.

Comment: It is working for me, so guessing it might have to do with a difference in versions in numpy or pandas @Kapital

Comment: I am working with Pandas version 0.25.3 and Numpy with 1.18.1.